# Bad Argument Handling in C: "Expected " + str(status) + " got " + str(child.returncode))"

Tags: python, c, file, file-io, exception

I have the following code:

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {

    case 'i':
        inFile = strdup(optarg);
        break;
    case 'o':
        outFile = strdup(optarg);
        break;
    default:

        //usage(argv[0]);
        //error_usage(argv[0]);
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <-i input file> <-o output file>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        }

    }
 }
```

which is fed to a program running like this:
`./program -i inFile -o outFile`

But the program which tests my program (not written by me) gives me this error:
`Expected " + str(status) + " got " + str(child.returncode))`

Do you know how should I have possibly handled bad arguments rather than what I have done above? Please provide me a code snippets rather than just words because it would be hard for me to figure out without code.

Comment: What makes you think the error has anything to do with argument handling?

Comment: Why is this tagged as python? I don't see any python here

Comment: And why `file` and `file-io`, there's no file processing here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be with the testing program, not with your code; it isn't passing the right arguments (or passing the right arguments the wrong way), and then getting all annoyed when your program tells it that it was wrong.

Printing an error to stderr and returning EXIT_FAILURE is considered the "right" way to handle bad arguments, otherwise if you pipe the output of one program into another like this:

```
ls --cookies! | sed 's/[.].*//'
```

and ls were to pretend like nothing went wrong, sed would process the usage information rather than the contents of the directory as expected.